# Why MacVim does not display some fonts properly?

Tags: vim, fonts, macvim

OS: Mac OS X 10.10.3
MacVim: 7.4.712

I am trying to use MacVim to write LaTeX instead of Sublime Text. 
So I set the font "Lucida Grande" from menu of MacVim but it looked strange:

[image: Lucida Grande in MacVim]

This is what Lucida Grande looks like in Sublime Text:

[image: Lucida Grande in Sublime Text]

Then I set "Helvetica" in MacVim and it looks like:

[image: Helvetica in MacVim]

It seems that MacVim tries to display fonts in mono but this is not what I want. How could I set the font properly in MacVim just like what Sublime Text does?

Comment: Use monospaced fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While GVIM / MacVim can use proportional fonts (on certain platforms), there's no way around the screen-cell based addressing in Vim; it's a fundamental concept (taken from the terminal), and many features (like *blockwise selections*) depend on it.

So, you have to live with the fact that an `i` will take as much horizontal space as a `W`, and choose a corresponding (monospaced) font accordingly. This way, your editor will look much better :-)